# Primefaces rio theme menu

Tags: primefaces

How to get the [primefaces rio](https://www.primefaces.org/eos/rio/dashboard.xhtml#) left navigation caret menu? In the dashboard page when I click on John Wilkings, four items are displayed. I want to implement this functionality for my menu. Where can I get the dashboard left navigation code? Here's what I tried:

```
<pr:menu>
    <p:submenu label="Label">
        <p:menuitem value="Information" title="Information" icon="fa fa-check" outcome="information">
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:submenu>
<pr:menu>
```

I also enclosed the above code in  like it's in barcelona, still it's not working.

Comment: Your tagging is wrong. This question has nothing to do with the primefaces-extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The source is your friend, you can find the demo pages in your rio zip. Just extract it and go to tag -> src -> main -> webapp. The layoutmenu.xhtml is in the subfolder WEB-INF.

Here's the code part you're searching for:

```
    <ul class="layout-menu">
        <li>
            <a class="menulink ripplelink">
                <i class="icon-round58 Fs40"></i>
                <span class="Fs18">John Wilkins<i class="icon-downwards Fright Fs20"></i><br /><span class="Fs12 FontRobotoLight">Sr. System Administrator</span></span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="menulink ripplelink"><i class="icon-user158 Fs16"></i> User Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menulink ripplelink"><i class="icon-two385 Fs16"></i> Change User</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menulink ripplelink"><i class="icon-settings49 Fs16"></i> System Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menulink ripplelink"><i class="icon-thermostat1 Fs16"></i> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: there are plain html codes. I believe the original xhtml will be having primefaces tags like i've added in my question.

Comment: No, the "John Wilkins" menu above is plain html. Only the rest of the menu is a special primefaces menu